# using heat map() with data frame from read.csv

Tags: r, heatmap, read.csv

in the following code:

```
data<-as.matrix(mtcars)
data
heatmap(data)
```

mtcars is converted to a numerical matrix which can be read by heatmap.  If I try the same code on a data frame generated by read.csv, I get a character matrix, which cannot:

```
>test<-read.csv("workbook2.csv")
> test
  a  e  f   g
1 b  1  2   3
2 c  4  5   6
3 d -1 -5 -10

> as.matrix(test)
     a   e    f    g    
[1,] "b" " 1" " 2" "  3"
[2,] "c" " 4" " 5" "  6"
[3,] "d" "-1" "-5" "-10"
```

what is different about the data frame of mtcars, and how do you convert the product of read.csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default in read.csv is to number the rows and include the first column in the data frame.  To create a data frame that can be correctly read by as.matrix, use

```
test<-read.csv("workbook2.csv", row.names=1)
```